# Remove auto justification on /cvitem

Tags: spacing, moderncv, justification

on "my about me" section at the beginning of the document i want to have several \cvitem elements without the first "date" argument something like the picture below. Now, the first row is not correctly justified since i got several spaces between words while i would like to have just a normal spacing:

```
\cvitem{}{Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester ,\underline{ \href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}}. Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
```

This is what i get:

[image]

Of course the text is dummy but the number of words and the structure is the same of the real inserted text and as you can see the first row is not well spaced.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you really need that `\underline`? Why not use an other color for marking a link?

Comment: Thanks! Do u think this can be something related to my problem? I just followed the common pattern of underlying words to evidence a clickable link !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at last three possibilities to get rid of the big white space:

1. Forget underlining! Then your link is breakable and you get a proper layout:

   ```
   \cvitem{}{Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
     \href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}. 
     Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
   ```
2. Forget underlining, use a different color instead. Then your link is breakable and you get a proper layout:

   ```
   \cvitem{}{Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
     \textcolor{red}{\href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}}. 
     Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
   ```
3. If you insist in underlining (that makes your link to be **unbreakable**!) you can for example use package `ragged2e` to be able to use command `\RaggedRight` with possible hyphenating like:

   ```
   \usepackage{ragged2e} % <===============================================
   ...
   \cvitem{}{\RaggedRight Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
     \underline{\href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}}. 
     Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
   ```

See all these posibilities together in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <===============================================

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}
\cvitem{}{Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
  \href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}. 
  Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
\cvitem{}{Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
  \textcolor{red}{\href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}}. 
  Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
\cvitem{}{\RaggedRight Long experience in eating Pizza and sweety donuts, matress tester, 
  \underline{\href{https://example.org//}{Best Dad of the alcoholic anonymous circle}}. 
  Never Hungry. Never foolish.}
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

IMHO the best looking possibility is 2. You can see the link, because it is coloured and you got a proper layout.

Underlining forces you to use a justification of the text only on the left and such an single paragraph with left justificated text breaks the complete layout of the cv, which is based on justifing left and right ...

Comment: Thank you ! Your solution is extremely detailed and well made. Actually, i'm using the moderncv default blue color so for styling purposes i tried using your suggested n 2 with the \textcolor{blue} which results being a totally different blue wrt the one i use for sections. Is there anything i can do about this? I do not know how to replicate the same blue as the default blue style. An alternative would be using just some bold formatting for highlighting my link but i do not if this will be appreciated so much

Comment: try `color1` instead my used `red` for the link color. `color1` is predefined by class `moderncv`.

Comment: Wow, so basically i could define new rgb colors coordinated in the relative sty class and this will affect whole my document color style?

Comment: You do not need to change the sty file, you can simply redefine the predefined colors in your preamble of your TeX code/CV ...

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help